# Android - looping for getJsonObject goes wrong

Tags: android

I want to create `jsonObject` with output,

this is the code i used to get `jsonObject` :

```
public JSONObject getJsonObject() {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    try {
        obj.put("id", id);
        obj.put("nilai", ratingStar);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return obj;
}
```

but when i loop the json using this code inside button.onClick :

```
 int size = adapter3.getCount();
 StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
 JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
 for (int i=0;i<=size;i++){
      b.append(jArray.put(adapter3.getItem(i).getJsonObject()));
 }
 TextView Star = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.test);
 Star.setText(b.toString());
```

why the output goes wrong?

the output gonna be like :

```
[{"id":"1","nilai":"1"},
[{"id":"1","nilai":"1"},
[{"id":"2","nilai":"1"},
[{"id":"1","nilai":"1"},
[{"id":"2","nilai":"1"},
[{"id":"3","nilai":"1"},
[{"id":"1","nilai":"1"},
[{"id":"2","nilai":"1"},
[{"id":"3","nilai":"1"},
[{"id":"4","nilai":"1"},
[{"id":"1","nilai":"1"},
[{"id":"2","nilai":"1"},
[{"id":"3","nilai":"1"},
[{"id":"4","nilai":"1"},
[{"id":"5","nilai":"1"},
```

it's like the output repeating the id from `1 | 1_2 | 1_2_3 | 1_2_3_4 | 1_2_3_4_5`

did i doing something wrong? why the output is repeating like that

**EDIT**

`Pertanyaan.java`

```
public class Pertanyaan {
private String id;
private float ratingStar;
private String ask;

Pertanyaan(String id, int ratingStar, String ask) {
    this.id = id;
    this.ratingStar = ratingStar;
    this.ask = ask;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

float getRatingStar() {
    return ratingStar;
}

void setRatingStar(float ratingStar) {
    this.ratingStar = ratingStar;
}

public String getAsk() {
    return ask;
}

public JSONObject getJsonObject() {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    try {
        obj.put("id", id);
        obj.put("nilai", ratingStar);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return obj;
}
}
```

`PertanyaanAdapter.java`

```js
class PertanyaanAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Pertanyaan> {

    private AppCompatActivity activity;
    private List<Pertanyaan> movieList;

    PertanyaanAdapter(AppCompatActivity context, int resource, List<Pertanyaan> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.activity = context;
        this.movieList = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public Pertanyaan getItem(int position) {
        return movieList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_listview, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            //holder.ratingBar.getTag(position);
        }

        holder.ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(onRatingChangedListener(position));

        holder.ratingBar.setTag(position);
        holder.ratingBar.setRating(getItem(position).getRatingStar());
        holder.movieName.setText(getItem(position).getAsk());
        holder.id.setText(getItem(position).getId());

        return convertView;
    }

    private RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener onRatingChangedListener(final int position) {
        return new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float v, boolean b) {
                Pertanyaan item = getItem(position);
                assert item != null;
                item.setRatingStar(v);
                Log.i("Adapter", "star: " + v);
            }
        };
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        private RatingBar ratingBar;
        private TextView movieName;
        private TextView id;

        ViewHolder(View view) {
            ratingBar = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.rate_img);
            movieName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
            id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textid);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are putting the values multiple times

Comment: Might be a buffer string that doesn't get reset. So insead of having the value "" before you put your value, it keeps the previous one in memory. So, instead of doing : `1 -> "" -> 2 -> "" -> 3`, it does `1 -> 2 -> 3`, so the strings do `1 -> 12 -> 123` instead of `1 -> 2 -> 3`. In clear, check that your string is properly reset between insertions

Comment: @dondo : Can you please share code where you are putting jsonObject in each item ?

Comment: @FlorentUguet but when i use this code `b.append("No : " + (i + 1) + " - " + "Star = " + adapter3.getItem(i).getRatingStar() + "\n");` the output is right, likes **No : 1 - Star = 1, No : 2 - Star = 2,etc**

Comment: @Vinodh ok, ill edit the post now

Comment: @dondo : I think inside loop, this is incorrect  : jArray.put(adapter3.getItem(i).getJsonObject()), you put all the data in loop. and then append to the stringBuilder

Comment: @dondo : One advice. In Android java, we use lower camelcase while creating variables. So, TextView Star should start with small letter "star".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i=0;i<=size;i++){
      b.append(jArray.put(adapter3.getItem(i).getJsonObject()));
}
```

Your jArray :

```
i = 0
[{"id":"1","nilai":"1"},

i = 1
[{"id":"1","nilai":"1"},
[{"id":"2","nilai":"1"},

i = 2
[{"id":"1","nilai":"1"},
[{"id":"2","nilai":"1"},
[{"id":"3","nilai":"1"},
```

The error is simple. You keep adding data to your jArray, and reinsert the whole array inside b.
On i = 0, it has 1 value.
But on i = 1, since you **put** the new string inside it, it still keeps the previous one inside, so you have 2 values inside the array, and so on.

The solution is to insert the array inside b only once, after you have fully filled it.

```
for (int i=0;i<=size;i++){
      jArray.put(adapter3.getItem(i).getJsonObject());
}
b.append(jArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 int size = adapter3.getCount();
 StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
 JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
 for (int i=0;i<=size;i++){
     jArray.put(adapter3.getItem(i).getJsonObject());
 }
 b.append(jArray.toString());
 TextView Star = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.test);
 Star.setText(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

you must set the Id and ratingStar or passing the value throught getJsonObject, i think by read that code, you have static value of id a nd ratingStar

```
public JSONObject getJsonObject() {
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
try {
    obj.put("id", id);
    obj.put("nilai", ratingStar);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return obj;
}
```